# Failed to publish web layer - ArcGIS Pro and ArcGIS Portal

Tags: arcgis-pro, arcgis-portal, hosted-feature-layer

I'm attempting to create a new hosted Service Layer, from a FileGDB, on ArcGIS Portal, using the publication tools inside of ArcGIS Pro.

I have done this successfully before with other data.
This morning however, when attempting to create a new Hosted layer, it fails.

Using the standard "Share as Web Layer" tools in ArcGIS Pro, I configure a Feature layer type and share with everyone in organisation. None of this is new.

However this time, I am getting a generic error message "Failed to Publish Web layer" inside of ArcGIS Pro. When attempting to create the service layer from the ArcGIS Portal admin page, the process just hangs.

"Failed to Publish Web Layer" message is not very helpful at all and there are no further details in the application, so I'm just looking for some starting points to help narrow down the investigation. At this stage I've only found this article, which doesn't help unfortunately.

https://community.esri.com/thread/210811-arcgis-pro-failed-to-publish-web-layer-to-portal-for-arcgis

Answer (score 2):

Goodness me, its straight up embarrassing but I solved the problem.

To answer my own question, a starting point would have been to:

**Check the source data for compatibility.**

Upon inspection, two of the source data attribute headings were in inverted comma's. ArcGIS Pro had created this as part of data translation, in order to cater for upstream attribute names that had spaces in them. (This was a result of an upstream data import process.)
Once I changed the field names to not have inverted commas, the service creation process was successful.